# How to create Regular expresssion for supporting xregexp for supporting UTF8 characters and some other characters

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string, xregexp

I want support Numeric, Alphabetic, special, and unicode characters. Here, what i have created the Regexp.

```
var regex = XRegExp("^(\\p{L}|([A-Za-z0-9\!\@\$\%\&\-\=\+\*\#\;\:\,\.\/\?]))+$");

regex.test(αβγδεζηθ); //returns false >> Non-ASCII characters entered
regex.test(αa@123); //returns false
regex.test(ab@123); //returns true
```

The above expression is not supporting utf8 characters. Please help.
The special characters defined in regexp are valid and they are supporting but utf8 characters are not supporting.

I am not able to identify where is the problem.

Please help.

Comment: Do you have [the Unicode plugin](http://xregexp.com/plugins/#unicode) installed?

Comment: I have already added unicode plugin. in jsp page added these two script tags :
<script src="js/xregexp.js"></script> 
<script src="js/unicode-base.js"></script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I’m a contributor to XRegExp — I wrote the scripts that generate the data for the Unicode plugin. Are you sure you have the Unicode plugin installed?

---

If you just need a single Unicode-aware regular expression, you may not want to pull in the entire XRegExp library + its Unicode plugin for just that. An alternative solution would be to use a build script that compiles the regular expression using [Regenerate](http://mths.be/regenerate) and [the Unicode data packages](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/unicode-7.0.0).

Here’s what that would look like in Node.js:

```
var regenerate = require('regenerate');

// Decimal digit number (Nd)
var Nd = require('unicode-7.0.0/categories/Nd/code-points');
// Letter (L)
var L = require('unicode-7.0.0/categories/L/code-points');

var set = regenerate() // Start with an empty set.
    .add(Nd) // Add “Decimal digit number (Nd)” code points
    .add(L) // Add “Letter (L)” code points
    .add( // Add some other symbols
        '!', '@', '$', '%', '&', '-', '=', '+', '*', '#', ';', ':', ',',
        '.', '/', '?'
    );
// Print the result.
console.log(set.toString());
```

Run `npm install regenerate unicode-7.0.0`, and then run this script as follows:

```
node generate-regular-expression.js
```

It will print the following output:

```
[!#-&\*-;=\?-Za-z\xAA\xB5\xBA\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xF6\xF8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u037F\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u052F\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u0660-\u0669\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07C0-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0-\u08B2\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0966-\u096F\u0971-\u0980\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09E6-\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0AE6-\u0AEF\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CE6-\u0CEF\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E50-\u0E59\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F20-\u0F29\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F-\u1049\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u1090-\u1099\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u16F1-\u16F8\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191E\u1946-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u19D0-\u19D9\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B50-\u1B59\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C4D-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA69D\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA7AD\uA7B0\uA7B1\uA7F7-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8D0-\uA8D9\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA900-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF-\uA9D9\uA9E0-\uA9E4\uA9E6-\uA9FE\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA50-\uAA59\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA7E-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uAB30-\uAB5A\uAB5C-\uAB5F\uAB64\uAB65\uABC0-\uABE2\uABF0-\uABF9\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF10-\uFF19\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC]|\uD800[\uDC00-\uDC0B\uDC0D-\uDC26\uDC28-\uDC3A\uDC3C\uDC3D\uDC3F-\uDC4D\uDC50-\uDC5D\uDC80-\uDCFA\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEA0-\uDED0\uDF00-\uDF1F\uDF30-\uDF40\uDF42-\uDF49\uDF50-\uDF75\uDF80-\uDF9D\uDFA0-\uDFC3\uDFC8-\uDFCF]|\uD801[\uDC00-\uDC9D\uDCA0-\uDCA9\uDD00-\uDD27\uDD30-\uDD63\uDE00-\uDF36\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF67]|\uD802[\uDC00-\uDC05\uDC08\uDC0A-\uDC35\uDC37\uDC38\uDC3C\uDC3F-\uDC55\uDC60-\uDC76\uDC80-\uDC9E\uDD00-\uDD15\uDD20-\uDD39\uDD80-\uDDB7\uDDBE\uDDBF\uDE00\uDE10-\uDE13\uDE15-\uDE17\uDE19-\uDE33\uDE60-\uDE7C\uDE80-\uDE9C\uDEC0-\uDEC7\uDEC9-\uDEE4\uDF00-\uDF35\uDF40-\uDF55\uDF60-\uDF72\uDF80-\uDF91]|\uD803[\uDC00-\uDC48]|\uD804[\uDC03-\uDC37\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDC83-\uDCAF\uDCD0-\uDCE8\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDD03-\uDD26\uDD36-\uDD3F\uDD50-\uDD72\uDD76\uDD83-\uDDB2\uDDC1-\uDDC4\uDDD0-\uDDDA\uDE00-\uDE11\uDE13-\uDE2B\uDEB0-\uDEDE\uDEF0-\uDEF9\uDF05-\uDF0C\uDF0F\uDF10\uDF13-\uDF28\uDF2A-\uDF30\uDF32\uDF33\uDF35-\uDF39\uDF3D\uDF5D-\uDF61]|\uD805[\uDC80-\uDCAF\uDCC4\uDCC5\uDCC7\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDD80-\uDDAE\uDE00-\uDE2F\uDE44\uDE50-\uDE59\uDE80-\uDEAA\uDEC0-\uDEC9]|\uD806[\uDCA0-\uDCE9\uDCFF\uDEC0-\uDEF8]|\uD808[\uDC00-\uDF98]|[\uD80C\uD840-\uD868\uD86A-\uD86C][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD80D[\uDC00-\uDC2E]|\uD81A[\uDC00-\uDE38\uDE40-\uDE5E\uDE60-\uDE69\uDED0-\uDEED\uDF00-\uDF2F\uDF40-\uDF43\uDF50-\uDF59\uDF63-\uDF77\uDF7D-\uDF8F]|\uD81B[\uDF00-\uDF44\uDF50\uDF93-\uDF9F]|\uD82C[\uDC00\uDC01]|\uD82F[\uDC00-\uDC6A\uDC70-\uDC7C\uDC80-\uDC88\uDC90-\uDC99]|\uD835[\uDC00-\uDC54\uDC56-\uDC9C\uDC9E\uDC9F\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCA6\uDCA9-\uDCAC\uDCAE-\uDCB9\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC3\uDCC5-\uDD05\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDD0D-\uDD14\uDD16-\uDD1C\uDD1E-\uDD39\uDD3B-\uDD3E\uDD40-\uDD44\uDD46\uDD4A-\uDD50\uDD52-\uDEA5\uDEA8-\uDEC0\uDEC2-\uDEDA\uDEDC-\uDEFA\uDEFC-\uDF14\uDF16-\uDF34\uDF36-\uDF4E\uDF50-\uDF6E\uDF70-\uDF88\uDF8A-\uDFA8\uDFAA-\uDFC2\uDFC4-\uDFCB\uDFCE-\uDFFF]|\uD83A[\uDC00-\uDCC4]|\uD83B[\uDE00-\uDE03\uDE05-\uDE1F\uDE21\uDE22\uDE24\uDE27\uDE29-\uDE32\uDE34-\uDE37\uDE39\uDE3B\uDE42\uDE47\uDE49\uDE4B\uDE4D-\uDE4F\uDE51\uDE52\uDE54\uDE57\uDE59\uDE5B\uDE5D\uDE5F\uDE61\uDE62\uDE64\uDE67-\uDE6A\uDE6C-\uDE72\uDE74-\uDE77\uDE79-\uDE7C\uDE7E\uDE80-\uDE89\uDE8B-\uDE9B\uDEA1-\uDEA3\uDEA5-\uDEA9\uDEAB-\uDEBB]|\uD869[\uDC00-\uDED6\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD86D[\uDC00-\uDF34\uDF40-\uDFFF]|\uD86E[\uDC00-\uDC1D]|\uD87E[\uDC00-\uDE1D]
```

This can be used directly as part of a regular expression literal.

The main advantage of this approach is that you’ll never have to tweak the regular expression manually. Instead, you can just change the script that generates it by adding or removing some symbols, then running it again. The code of the script is much more readable and maintainable than any regular expression, IMHO. Also, the output is as compact as possible: rather than introducing an entire library as a run-time dependency, you just insert a single regular expression literal.